# How to find who did a git cherry-pick?

Tags: git

Given a commit that has been cherry picked, what is the git command that can show who performed that `git cherry-pick` operation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+who+did+cherry-pick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that prints the log data can print both the author *and* the committer.  The author of a cherry-picked commit defaults to the author of the original commit itself, while the committer is (unless overridden) the person who did the cherry-pick.  Hence:

```
git show --pretty=fuller <hash>
```

will, for instance do the trick, as will:

```
git log --no-walk --pretty=fuller <hash>
```

(`git show` will produce the diff against the parent(s) as well).